# Using json_extract to find in all objects in JSON array

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite-json1

How can json_extract be used to look through all objects in an array? It works if you knew the key, but I want to look at every single object and find the one that matches.

```
$.features[0].properties.TMPRIV_ID
```

How to get this to work?

```
$.features[*].properties.TMPRIV_ID
```

Comment: That code is not SQL. And standard SQL does not have a `json_extract` function. And why did you tag two different databases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have this flagged with MySQL and Sqlite, so I'm going to flip a coin and give a Sqlite answer.

Basically, you need to select from the `json_each()` row-valued function to iterate over each element of the array, and a where clause that filters just what you want (Which is where `json_extract()` comes into play):

```
sqlite> SELECT value FROM
  json_each('[{"name":"cat","type":"mammal"},{"name":"parrot","type":"bird"},{"name":"dog","type":"mammal"}]')
  WHERE json_extract(value, '$.type') = 'mammal';
value                         
------------------------------
{"name":"cat","type":"mammal"}
{"name":"dog","type":"mammal"}
```

If you want the results as a JSON array instead of a set of rows, use the `json_group_array()` aggregate function: `SELECT json_group_array(value) FROM ...`

Comment: Ah I see, you the json_each loops through it, nice! thanks!

Comment: @mobeen Not a clue. I don't use MySQL.